# Python xarray remove coordinates with all missing variables

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I import different netCDF files with xarray and eventually need to convert all of them to one panda dataframe. It's a file containing weather data, with many missing observations for certain latitudes and longitudes over time (because they are in the middle of the ocean). Coordinates: Lat, Long, Time; Variables: Temp, Pre.
Before converting to a dataframe, I want to get rid of these missing observations/whole coordinates. Is there an easy and efficient way to do that with xarray? I didn't find anything in the docs.

```
import pandas as pd 
import xarray as xr

path = 'Z:/Research/Climate_change/Climate_extreme_index/CRU data/'
temp_data = path+'cru_ts4.01.1901.2016.tmp.dat.nc'
pre_data = path+'cru_ts4.01.1901.2016.pre.dat.nc'

# Open netcdf 
def open_netcdf(datapath):
    print("Loading data...")
    data = xr.open_dataset(datapath, autoclose=True, drop_variables='stn', cache=True)
    return data
# Merge dataframes
data_temp = open_netcdf(temp_data)
data_pre = open_netcdf(pre_data)
all_data = xr.merge([data_temp, data_pre])

#################################################################
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 360, lon: 720, time: 1392)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float32 -179.75 -179.25 -178.75 -178.25 -177.75 -177.25 ...
  * lat      (lat) float32 -89.75 -89.25 -88.75 -88.25 -87.75 -87.25 -86.75 ...
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1901-01-16 1901-02-15 1901-03-16 ...
Data variables:
    tmp      (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    pre      (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
#########################################################
#Dataframe example
                           tmp  pre
lat    lon     time                
-89.75 -179.75 1901-01-16  NaN  NaN
               1901-02-15  NaN  NaN
               1901-03-16  NaN  NaN
               1901-04-16  NaN  NaN
               1901-05-16  NaN  NaN
               1901-06-16  NaN  NaN
               1901-07-16  NaN  NaN
               1901-08-16  NaN  NaN
               1901-09-16  NaN  NaN
               1901-10-16  NaN  NaN
               1901-11-16  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that converting the Dataset to a DataFrame before dropping NaNs is exactly the right solution.

One of the key differences between a pandas DataFrame with a MultiIndex and an xarray Dataset is that some index elements (time/lat/lon combinations) can be dropped in a MultiIndex without dropping *all* instances of the time, lat, or lon with a NaN. On the other hand, the DataArray models each dimension (time, lat, and lon) as orthogonal, meaning NaNs cannot be dropped without dropping an entire slice of the array. This is a core feature of the xarray data model.

As an example, here is a small dataset that matches the structure of your data:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd, numpy as np, xarray as xr

In [2]: ds = xr.Dataset({
   ...:     var: xr.DataArray(
   ...:         np.random.random((4, 3, 6)),
   ...:         dims=['time', 'lat', 'lon'],
   ...:         coords=[
   ...:             pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=4, freq='Q'),
   ...:             np.arange(-60, 90, 60),
   ...:             np.arange(-180, 180, 60)])
   ...:     for var in ['tmp', 'pre']})
   ...:
```

We can create a fake land mask which will NaN out specific lat/lon combos for each time period

```
In [3]: land_mask = (np.random.random((1, 3, 6)) > 0.3)

In [4]: ds = ds.where(land_mask)

In [5]: ds.tmp
Out[5]:
<xarray.DataArray 'tmp' (time: 4, lat: 3, lon: 6)>
array([[[0.020626, 0.937496,      nan, 0.052608, 0.266924, 0.361297],
        [0.299442, 0.524904, 0.447275, 0.277471,      nan, 0.595671],
        [0.541777, 0.279131,      nan, 0.282487,      nan,      nan]],

       [[0.473278, 0.302622,      nan, 0.664146, 0.401243, 0.949998],
        [0.225176, 0.601039, 0.543229, 0.144694,      nan, 0.196285],
        [0.059406, 0.37001 ,      nan, 0.867737,      nan,      nan]],

       [[0.571011, 0.864374,      nan, 0.123406, 0.663951, 0.684302],
        [0.867234, 0.823417, 0.351692, 0.46665 ,      nan, 0.215644],
        [0.425196, 0.777346,      nan, 0.332028,      nan,      nan]],

       [[0.916069, 0.54719 ,      nan, 0.11225 , 0.560431, 0.22632 ],
        [0.605043, 0.991989, 0.880175, 0.3623  ,      nan, 0.629986],
        [0.222462, 0.698494,      nan, 0.56983 ,      nan,      nan]]])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-03-31 2010-06-30 2010-09-30 2010-12-31
  * lat      (lat) int64 -60 0 60
  * lon      (lon) int64 -180 -120 -60 0 60 120
```

You can see that no lat or lon index can be dropped without losing valid data. On the other hand, when the data is converted to a DataFrame, the lat/lon/time dimensions are stacked, meaning a single element in this index can be dropped without affecting other rows:

```
In [6]: ds.to_dataframe()
Out[6]:
                          tmp       pre
lat lon  time
-60 -180 2010-03-31  0.020626  0.605749
         2010-06-30  0.473278  0.192560
         2010-09-30  0.571011  0.850161
         2010-12-31  0.916069  0.415747
    -120 2010-03-31  0.937496  0.465283
         2010-06-30  0.302622  0.492205
         2010-09-30  0.864374  0.461739
         2010-12-31  0.547190  0.755914
    -60  2010-03-31       NaN       NaN
         2010-06-30       NaN       NaN
         2010-09-30       NaN       NaN
         2010-12-31       NaN       NaN
     0   2010-03-31  0.052608  0.529258
         2010-06-30  0.664146  0.116303
         2010-09-30  0.123406  0.389693
...                       ...       ...
 60  120 2010-03-31       NaN       NaN
         2010-06-30       NaN       NaN
         2010-09-30       NaN       NaN
         2010-12-31       NaN       NaN

[72 rows x 2 columns]
```

When `dropna()` is called on this DataFrame, no data is dropped:

```
In [7]: ds.to_dataframe().dropna(how='all')
Out[7]:
                          tmp       pre
lat lon  time
-60 -180 2010-03-31  0.020626  0.605749
         2010-06-30  0.473278  0.192560
         2010-09-30  0.571011  0.850161
         2010-12-31  0.916069  0.415747
    -120 2010-03-31  0.937496  0.465283
         2010-06-30  0.302622  0.492205
         2010-09-30  0.864374  0.461739
         2010-12-31  0.547190  0.755914
     0   2010-03-31  0.052608  0.529258
         2010-06-30  0.664146  0.116303
         2010-09-30  0.123406  0.389693
         2010-12-31  0.112250  0.485259
     60  2010-03-31  0.266924  0.795056
         2010-06-30  0.401243  0.299577
         2010-09-30  0.663951  0.359567
         2010-12-31  0.560431  0.933291
...                       ...       ...
 60  0   2010-03-31  0.282487  0.148216
         2010-06-30  0.867737  0.643767
         2010-09-30  0.332028  0.471430
         2010-12-31  0.569830  0.380992
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the [dropna](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.dropna.html) function, e.g.

```
all_data.dropna('time', how='all')
```

But as of now it is only implemented along a single dimension at once, so i am not sure if it does what you wish. I understand you want to remove those lat, lon pairs that are nan for all times? I think you have to turn lat, lon into a pandas [multiindex](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/data-structures.html?highlight=multiindex#multiindex-coordinates) coordinate and then use dropna along this new dimension.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Create some example data with two pixels that have NA at all times.
data = np.random.rand(10,5,6)
data[:, 3, 2] = np.ones((10)) * np.nan
data[:, 0, 4] = np.ones((10)) * np.nan

# Make the dataset.
ds = xr.Dataset({"my_var": (["time", "x", "y"], data)})

# Create a MultiIndex
ds = ds.stack(pixel=("x", "y"))

# Drop the pixels that only have NA values.
ds = ds.dropna("pixel", how="all")
```

And in case you're opening `ds` from a single large netCDF, you probably want to chunk it before running the last two lines.

```
ds = ds.chunk("auto")
```